# Why are the DIV Containers only showing off with pixel and do not with percentage

Tags: html, css

I just want to design a simple chat with CSS for learning purpose, but I can not understand, why the 2 DIV container are not showing off like I would them to.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            font-size: 36px;
        }

        #messages {
            height: 95%;/* Does not work but for example 500px works */
            width: 80%;
            float: left;
            background: grey;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #users {
            height: 95%;/* Does not work but for example 500px works */
            width: 20%;
            background: dimgrey;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        input {
            width: 100%;
            height: 5%;
            background: lightgrey;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <div id="users"></div>
        <input type="text">
    </section>
</body>
```

So why does it work with px and with % it does not ?

Comment: The div you want to assign a % height on checks its parentnode width to calculate the height %%.

Comment: Sorry, bad mistake, parent element must have height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using percentages for height, the height is relative to a parent, so you need to establish a baseline. Typically this is done by setting the height on the html and body elements. In your case, you'd also need to set it on the section:

```
html, body, section {
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/40ktrktc/)**

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Could you perhaps tell me, why the input textfield with 100% width is a little bit longer then 80% messages-div and 20% users-div ? At the end, both of them should be 100% and I do not get, why the input textfield is a bit longer...

Comment: It's related to the default border/margin/padding on the input. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Why is it enough to give the height to show the elements correctly ? What is with the width ?

Comment: Because block level elements occupy 100% of the width of their parent by default.